# How to populate carousel view with same object but displaying different data each time MAUI. DataTemplateSelector not working

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I have an object and I want to use different data visuals for each view in the CarouselView. I plan for the first slide to be a description, details and then charts.

I have tried to change the DataTemplate but it's not working. I get the error 'System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'' on the line`View = (View)template.CreateContent();`

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Acre.Views.PropertyInfoPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Acre.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Acre.Models"
             xmlns:ak="clr-namespace:AlohaKit.Controls;assembly=AlohaKit"
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:Acre.Services"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:PropertyInfoViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyDescription">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="Description" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding FullDescription}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding PropertyPartnersString}" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
            
        </DataTemplate>
        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyDetails">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="PropertyDetails" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
            
        </DataTemplate>
        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyRentHistory">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="PropertyRentHistory" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyValueHistory">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="PropertyValueHistory" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

        <templates:PropertyTemplateSelector x:Key="propertyTemplateSelector"
                                            PropertyDescriptionTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyDescription}"
                                            PropertyDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyDetails}"
                                            PropertyValueHistoryTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyRentHistory}"
                                            PropertyReturnsHistoryTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyValueHistory}"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="20, 60, 20, 20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="175" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Info" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" Grid.RowSpan="2"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
        
        <Button Command="{Binding DeletePageCommand}"  Text="x" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="White" TextColor="Black" />

        <Frame Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" HeightRequest="300" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Black">
            <CarouselView x:Name="PropertyCarouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyImages}">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
        </Frame>
        
        <Border  Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" Grid.RowSpan="11" Stroke="white">
            <CarouselView x:Name="PropertyOverviewCarouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertiesToBuy, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource propertyTemplateSelector}" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" >
            </CarouselView>
        </Border>

        <Button Command="{Binding OpenBuyPageCommand}" Text="Buy Share" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="18" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

```
using Acre.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Acre.Services
{
    public class PropertyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate PropertyDescriptionTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PropertyDetailsTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PropertyValueHistoryTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate PropertyReturnsHistoryTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            PropertyModel propertyModel = (PropertyModel)item;

            if (propertyModel.DataTemplate == "PropertyDescription")
                return PropertyDescriptionTemplate;

            else if (propertyModel.DataTemplate == "PropertyDetails")
                return PropertyDetailsTemplate;

            else if (propertyModel.DataTemplate == "PropertyRentHistory")
                return PropertyValueHistoryTemplate;

            else if (propertyModel.DataTemplate == "PropertyValueHistory")
                return PropertyReturnsHistoryTemplate;

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Acre.Views;
using Acre.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Acre.Models;
using Acre;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui;

namespace Acre.ViewModels
{
    internal class PropertyInfoViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PropertyModel> PropertiesToBuy { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfoPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public PropertyModel PropertyToBuy { get; set; }
        public List<ImageSource> PropertyImages { get; set; }
        public string PropertyPartnersString { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeletePageCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand OpenBuyPageCommand { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfoViewModel()
        {
            DeletePageCommand = new Command(DeletePage);
            OpenBuyPageCommand = new Command(OpenBuyPage);

            GetPropertyInformationForDisplay();
            AddIMagesToImageCarouselView();
        }

        public void DeletePage()
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        public void GetPropertyInformationForDisplay()
        {
            PropertyApiService propertyApiService = new PropertyApiService();

            PropertyToBuy = propertyApiService.Get(int.Parse(Preferences.Get("PropertyIdToBuy", "10000"))).Result;

            PropertyToBuy.PropertyPartnersDisplayString = "In partnership with " + PropertyToBuy.DevelopmentCompany + " & " + PropertyToBuy.ManagementCompany;

            var propertiesList = AddPropertyToBuyToList();

            PropertiesToBuy = new ObservableCollection<PropertyModel>(propertiesList);
        }

        public List<PropertyModel> AddPropertyToBuyToList()
        {
            List<PropertyModel> list = new List<PropertyModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                PropertyModel tempProperty = PropertyToBuy;
                if (i == 0)
                    tempProperty.DataTemplate = "PropertyDescription";
                else if (i == 1)
                    tempProperty.DataTemplate = "PropertyDetails";
                else if (i == 2)
                    tempProperty.DataTemplate = "PropertyRentHistory";
                else if (i == 3)
                    tempProperty.DataTemplate = "PropertyValueHistory";

                list.Add(PropertyToBuy);
            }

            //remove datatemplateselector
            //hide the other datatemplates in bool list property
            //and then give each object an isHide 

            return list;
        }

        public void AddIMagesToImageCarouselView()
        {
            PropertyImages = new List<ImageSource>
            {
                ImageSource.FromFile(PropertyToBuy.ImageOne),
                ImageSource.FromFile(PropertyToBuy.ImageTwo),
                ImageSource.FromFile(PropertyToBuy.ImageThree)
            };
        }

        public void OpenBuyPage()
        {
            if (!Preferences.ContainsKey("CurrentUser"))
                App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());

            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BuyPage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what else to say.

Spent a while trying a variety of things.

My other option is to just create my own adaptation of a ScrollView that snaps but I want to use the indicator.

Comment: your `ItemsSource` is a `List<ImageSource>` but your template selector is expecting `PropertyModel`.  You also have a `DataTemplate` hardcoded in your XAML - I don't see where you are actually using the template selector

Comment: The empty border is where the carousel view should go. The other one works as intended.

Comment: you need to debug `AddPropertyToBuyToList` - it won't do what you think it does

Comment: Yeh just changed it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you still getting the same exception?  The line mentioned isn't included in the code you posted.  Have you stepped through that method, or looked at the stack trace?

Comment: Yehp. I don't really know what was causing the error as that's how Microsoft specifies to do it in their documentation. 

But I've fixed it now and I did two things:

Added the selector and the templates to the App.xaml resource dictionary. I then also removed the <Viewcell>

Comment: Please add "Your Answer" below, showing how you fixed it. This makes it more obvious that your problem is solved. After 48 hours, you can come back and accept (checkmark) your own answer. Thanks.